# Zipping a large folder fails

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to archive logs to capture an intermittent fault where my logs are regularly overwritten. I wish to archive the logs to ensure I capture the required event.

I have written what appears to be funcional code to perform this, however if the folder is very large, the zip fails. If I point it to a smaller directory, it works without issue.
There is no error generated, and I would appreciate any assistance in identifying the cause.

As I have never programmed in VBS before, I apologise in advance if this seems a simple question.

```
Option Explicit 
dim objFSO, objFolder, FolderToZip, ziptoFile 
dim ShellApp, eFile, oNewZip, strZipHeader 
dim ZipName, Folder, i, Zip 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Program Files\afolder") 


Wscript.Sleep 2000 
Set oNewZip = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Archive\logs_" & day(date) & month(Date) & Year(date)& ".zip", 8, True) 
strZipHeader = "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) 
For i = 0 to 17 
 strZipHeader = strZipHeader & Chr(0) 
Next 
oNewZip.Write strZipHeader 
oNewZip.Close 
Set oNewZip = Nothing 
WScript.Sleep 5000 

FolderToZip = "D:\Program Files\afolder" 
ZipToFile = "C:\Archive\logs_" & day(date) & month(Date) & Year(date)& ".zip"
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
Set Zip= ShellApp.NameSpace(ZipToFile) 
Set Folder= ShellApp.NameSpace(FolderToZip) 
Zip.CopyHere(FolderToZip) 
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

Comment: "if the folder is very large": Define "very large". A large number of files? A large number of bytes? What is the code using `oNewZip` supposed to accomplish? (It creates a file, writes 18 repetitions of a PKZIP header followed by a binary 0 to it, and then saves it. It has no impact on your question, so I'm just curious why you felt it was necessary to include it.)

Comment: By large, I have one directory with 1000 individual files and 1 Gig in size.

Comment: The program fails at about 50-100 files. Regarding the question about usng oNewZip, the answer here is basically that I don't know what I'm doing. I am very new to VBS, so my understanding of it is poor. I can only apologise again, I would normally spend longer researching before posting, but my fault is starting to cause me some pain, so I thought I'd cheat a bit.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because it doesn't seem to work either. Looking into it now.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky if no files are deleted. You should research on `WshShell` and install 7zip as it supports command mode.

Comment: @PatricK Care to explain how `CopyHere` would delete files? Or how `WshShell` comes into play here in the first place? (hint: it doesn't)

Comment: @KenWhite The code worked just fine for me on ~1000 randomly generated 1 MB files. I'd just open the zip file for writing (`2`) instead of for appending (`8`). And you need to keep in mind that `CopyHere` runs asynchronously, so it may take some time until all files are added to the zip file. Something like this should help: `Do : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop Until Zip.NameSpace(objFSO.BuildPath(ZipFile, objFSO.GetFolder(FolderToZip).Name)).Items.Count = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderToZip).Files.Count`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers given that the OP says "written what appears to be funcional code" and "have never programmed in VBS before", it means that code was copied and modified from somewhere. If that is all the code he used, then he is save. My bad for using "WshShell", should have said `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` as it can be used to execute command line with 7z.exe

Answer (score 5):

Your code is a little more complicated than it needs to be, but it works in principle. What's causing the failures you're experiencing with large folders is the fixed 2 second delay at the end:

```
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

`CopyHere` runs asynchronously, meaning that it runs in the background while the script continues. However, after 2 seconds delay the script terminates (and the `Shell.Application` instance with it), whether `CopyHere` has finished or not. When you have numerous/large files the processing may well take more than 2 seconds.

That's why your script works fine for small folders, but not for large ones. The copying simply isn't finished when the script terminates after 2 seconds.

To avoid this, replace the fixed delay with a check that compares the number of processed files to the total file count:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

zipfile = "C:\Temp\logs_" & Day(Date) & Month(Date) & Year(Date) & ".zip"
fldr    = "C:\Temp\sample"
cnt     = fso.GetFolder(fldr).Files.Count

'create a new empty zip file
fso.OpenTextFile(zipfile, 2, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) _
  & String(18, Chr(0))

'start copying the files from the source folder to the zip file
Set zip = app.NameSpace(zipfile)
zip.CopyHere app.NameSpace(fldr).Items     '<- runs asynchronously!

'wait for CopyHere to finish
Do
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop Until zip.Items.Count = cnt
```

Comment: Ansgar,Your blood is worth bottling and I owe you a beer. I really appreaciate the quick response. I would never have picked that up. Not sure how I vote for you, but will once I work out how.

Comment: One further question if it is permitted, if a file is in use, the attempt to zip fails, is there a method to ignore the error and move onto the next file? I have seen mention of 'On Error Resume Next/On Error GoTo 0' but these appear to be more relevent to a iterated loop.

Comment: I have got it working (by reverting to an earlier version and adding your delay fix) I think this works because the files are copied, It would be good if there was a neater solution.

Comment: Snipet:
    For Each efile in objFolder.Files 
 If DateDiff("d",eFile.DateLastModified,Now) >= 2 Then 
  objFSO.MoveFile eFile,"C:\Temp\" 
 End If