# How can this vbscript work properly with run command?

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, cmd, zip

I want to compress some folders with the batch/vbs solution like here: https://superuser.com/a/112094

This one works, but the original solution uses the "sleep"- function and my archives have different filesizes, so that this wouldn´t work properly. My idea was to use the Run command (wait parameter), but it fails.

```
set FILETOZIP=C:\users\xyz\documents\folderOrfile
set TEMPDIR=C:\users\xyz\documents\temp
rmdir %TEMPDIR% /s /q
mkdir %TEMPDIR%
xcopy /s %FILETOZIP% %TEMPDIR%

echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > _zipIt.vbs
echo InputFolder = objArgs(0) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo ZipFile = objArgs(1) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> _zipIt.vbs
echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> _zipIt.vbs

echo theString = objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo objShell.Run theString, 1, true >> _zipIt.vbs

CScript  _zipIt.vbs  %TEMPDIR%  C:\users\xyz\documents\someArchive.zip 

pause
```

The error message is the following:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: objShell.Run

How can I achieve that the scripts wait till the zip is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing `Shell.Application` and `WScript.Shell` objects. Only the latter have a `Run` method. You'd have to change the line

```
echo objShell.Run theString, 1, true >> _zipIt.vbs
```

to

```
echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run theString, 1, true >> _zipIt.vbs
```

With that said, trying to `Run` what is returned by the `CopyHere` method won't help you at all. The issue with using `Shell.Application` for zipping files/folders is that the object is automatically destroyed when the (VB)script terminates, thus interrupting unfinished copy operations. Either define a long enough sleep time, or [wait in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22050803/1630171).

Answer (score 1):

Errors aside, if you want to wait until a file is created consider looking at [loops](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-loops.html) and [IF EXIST](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Something like this could work:

```
:CHECKFILE
IF EXIST C:\users\xyz\documents\someArchive.zip GOTO FOUNDFILE
GOTO CHECKFILE

:FOUNDFILE
REM Do something with the file here
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The VBScript code creates an empty zip file first, so checking for it's presence isn't necessary. Also, the issue at hand is that the COM object doing the compression runs asynchronously, but terminates when the script does, so the copying is aborted if it isn't already finished at that point.

Comment: Yeah, your answer did a good job of addressing the issues with his code (which is why I upvoted it) whereas I tried to answer his actual question of `How can I achieve that the scripts wait till the zip is created?` despite the other problems.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the code. All of the `echo` statements create one VBScript that is executed via `cscript _zipit.vbs ...`. This single VBScript both creates the zip file and copies files into it. Checking for the presence of the zip file before the VBScript is run creates an infinite loop.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I modified the `FOUNDFILE` section so that my answer is code agnostic

Comment: You still don't understand. The entire zip processing -creation and copying- is done by the VBScript. Processing starts when the VBScript is executed, and ends when the VBScript terminates. All of that is a single statement in the batch file (`cscript _zipit.vbs ...`), so no checking or looping you could do in the batch code is going to be of any help here.